# Error accessing 2 object reference each other in Java

Tags: java, pojo

I have created two POJO classes Author and Book. Where Author POJO class requires Book as an argument and Book POJO requires Author as an argument, i.e., both are bidirectionally related/circularly dependent.

Author Pojo class:

```
Public class Author{
Private Book book;
Private String authorname;
publicIndividual(Book book, String authorname){
this.authorname=authorname;
this.book = book
}
// getters and setters…
}
```

Book pojo class:

```
Public class Book{
Private Author author;
Private String bookname;
Private String id;
publicIndividual(String id, String bookname, Author author){
this.id=id
this.bookname = bookname;
this.author = author
}
// getters and setters…
}
```

Java Class to set data:

```
public final Author author = new Author(book, authorname);
public final Book book = new Book(id, bookname, author);
```

I am facing error "Illegal forward reference" since trying to call book method before it is initialized. How to achieve this incase of interdependent pojo classes?

Comment: Your model doesn't really make sense. A `Book` should be able to have multiple `Author`s. And an `Author` should be able to have multiple `Book`s

Comment: First create an `Author` by using `null` for the book, then create the `Book`, then call `author.setBook(book);`

Comment: Think about the dependency: an author may or may not have written a book (yet) but a book normally always has an author. So I'd create the author without any book reference. When creating a book I'd pass `author` to the `Book` constructor and inside that one I'd also call `author.addBook(this)` or so.

Comment: Btw, you might want to reformat your code snippets to show you've put some effort into your question (e.g. `private` instead of `Private`, `public Author(...)` and `public Book(...)` instead of `publicIndividual(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

Mainly since you have cross-reference you could just instantiate with null one reference and after set up properly.

```
public class TestRef
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Author author = new Author(new Book("1","bookname",null), "authorname");
        System.out.println(author+" Book.author::"+author.book.author);
        author.book.author=author;
        System.out.println(author+" Book.author::"+author.book.author);
    }
    static class Author{
        Book book;
        String authorname;
        public Author(Book book, String authorname)
        {
            this.authorname=authorname;
            this.book = book;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Author("+book+","+authorname+")";
        }
    }
    static class Book{
        Author author;
        String bookname;
        String id;
        public Book(String id, String bookname, Author author){
        this.id=id;
        this.bookname = bookname;
        this.author = author;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return bookname+"_"+id;
        }
    }   
}
```

Output

```
//with null ref on Book for Author
Author(bookname_1,authorname) Book.author::null
//after set up properly ref
Author(bookname_1,authorname) Book.author::Author(bookname_1,authorname)
```

Comment: Glad to be helpful !